# Declaring constant for different targets

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Is there is any way to declare constant in similar way as I can do with variable?

```
enum AppConstants {
         static var projectID: String {
          #if Target1
          return "1"
          #endif
          #if Target2
          return "2"
          #endif
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to check the target on a code level, create separate `AppContants` files for each target, and add the correct file to each target.

```
// AppContantsForTarget1.swift
// Include only in Target1
enum AppConstants {
    static let projectID = "1"
}

// AppContantsForTarget2.swift
// Include only in Target2
enum AppConstants {
    static let projectID = "2"
}
```